# Displaying images from dataDirectory in ionic2

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working on an app, using `ionic2`.

I'm storing a set of images that I downloaded from the server in the dataDirectory to save mobile traffic when the app is used without wi-fi.
Now, I would like to display them inside my template.

Is there a recommended way how the image should best be inserted?

I tried giving the `ion-img` or `img-tag`

the complete path (`file.dataDirectory + “myImg.jpg” -> "file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/myImg.jpg`”

(stored in my `imgPath` variable, the path is written after the `platform.ready` event), but only a broken image symbol is shown. When accessing images from my assets folder I do not encounter any problems, but how can I access the dataDirectory’s images?

```
<img width=“200” height=“200” [src]=“imgPath” *ngIf=“imgPath”>
```

Or do I have to read each image from the dataDirectory and store them in a local variable as a `base64` string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reason for showing broken image in IONIC.

1. If you are using live reload then sometime images are shown as broken image. You can run directly to see if it resolves your issue.
2. If you want to use base64 image, either you can save it SQLite or in local variable which may resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I retried without live reload and now my image is shown without the need to load everything via base64. I thought moving from emulator to actual device would solve the matter but it seems the problem (in my case) was the activated live reload.